# How to create a user without autologin after sign up on Meteor

Tags: authentication, meteor, hook, account

I'm building a Meteor app and I need to remove the autologin of Meteor after a user create an account.

I'm using accounts-password and accounts-entry for the UI (optional).

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent auto login after create user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360037/how-to-prevent-auto-login-after-create-user)

Comment: Yeah, it's duplicated. Sorry but I haven't found it before creating. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

This is a simple solution for logins by email, it deactivates autologins after user creation and denies later logins until the email address is verified:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {

    Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(attemptInfo) {

        if (attemptInfo.type == 'resume') return true;

        if (attemptInfo.methodName == 'createUser') return false;

        if (attemptInfo.methodName == 'login' && attemptInfo.allowed) {
            var verified = false;
            var email = attemptInfo.methodArguments[0].user.email;
            attemptInfo.user.emails.forEach(function(value, index) {
                if (email == value.address && value.verified) verified = true;
            });
            if (!verified) throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'Verify Email first!');
        }

        return true;
    });

}
```

Comment: The problem is with this, the code does not create the user. Because this validateLoginAttemp() runs before the createUser() somehow. When it returns false in the second if, meteor does not signup the new user, neither send the email confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following code:

Set a `firstLogin` flag on creation

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  user.firstLogin = true;
  return user;
});
```

Method to update the flag

```
Meteor.methods({
  updateUserFirstLogin: function(userId) {
    Meteor.users.update({
      _id: userId
    }, {
      $set: {
        'firstLogin': false
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Check if the user is a new one on login

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(attemptInfo) {
  if (!attemptInfo.user) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!attemptInfo.user.firstLogin) {
    return true;
  } else {
    Meteor.call('updateUserFirstLogin', attemptInfo.user._id);
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier approach:

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt((data) => {
    let diff = new Date() - new Date(data.user.createdAt);
    if (diff < 2000) {
        console.info('New user created -- denying autologin.');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

This sees that the user was literally just created, and so doesn't log it on.