# Calling Accounts.createUser from a method doesn't login the user

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am using a meteor method for user registration form. I have the following method:

```
Meteor.methods
    '/users/create': (new_user) ->
        # some additional validation here ...
        Accounts.createUser new_user
```

The problem is that users are created but not logged in. The method is located in a generic folder and is executed by both client and server.

Answer (score 2):

is there a problem if you create users on client side? like this.

```
Accounts.createUser({}, function(err) {
  if(!err){
    console.log("Yea we create an user")
  }
});
```

This will enabled `autologin` on default

You should that `Account.createUser` have differents behavior on `client` or `server`

**client**

If you create the user on the client side this function will login automatically the user when its successful created

**server**

on the server the function only return the new user _id

Comment: I need to do a few server side validations before actually calling createUser method

Comment: @check answer update in fact when you create the user on the server side it will don't come with autologin, it just return the current id of the user

Comment: Sure thing, the aforementioned code is executed on both client and server side, so on the client side, it should get the id from the server side, do I miss something here ?

Comment: well i don't do coffee, and i don't get you after google a little i get this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360037/how-to-prevent-auto-login-after-create-user)answer, take a look on it, seems like @dmacd got the answer to you